# Single function call to printf without using if statements?

Tags: c

I want to call `printf`, so it prints  `1 donut` 
if the `donuts` variable (of type `int`) has the value `1`, and `n widgets` otherwise, where `n` is the value of `widget`.

How can I make a single function call to `printf` to achieve this without using **any** `if` statement(s) or any other statement; the code must be a **single** call to `printf`?

Comment: If `if` is banned, use the ternary operator: `? :`.

Comment: Are you aware of what you're attempting to do? Kudos to @HolyBlackCat for actually giving you an `if` workaround, but in your explanation you say "so it prints `1 donut` **if** the `donuts` variable...". Until you can find a suitable way to explain your situation without using a term like "if", you probably won't find code that does what you need as `if` is already here for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

```
 printf(" %d %s\n", donuts == 1 ? donuts : widgets, donuts == 1 ? "donuts" : "widgets");
```

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ansi_c/ternary_operator_examples.htm

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.